# api для встраивания в систему страхователя функционала обмена данными ЭЛН с сервисами ФСС

Tags: api, сервисы

На сайте http://api-fss.ru предлагается api для встраивания в собственную систему страхователя функционала обмена данными ЭЛН с сервисами ФСС. Ау, разработчики!
Есть ли у кого опыт использования этого api? Отзовитесь, очень надо.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотеку api-fss.dll используем в АО "Адмиралтейские верфи" с 2018 г. Год работали с ГОСТ 2001, с лета 2019 перешли на ГОСТ 2012. Консольные приложения с сайта  http://api-fss.ru  использовали в тестовых целях, в работе сейчас не используем. Проблемы возникают только на стороне ФСС. Нормального технического сопровождения со стороны ФСС нет, сервисы падают, SSL-сертификат меняли 2 месяца и т.д.